# extra variables in legend when wrapping ggplot2 in plotly R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, plotly, aesthetics

I am having trouble making the legend of the following `ggplot` wrapped in `ggplotly()` show only one aesthetic.  It currently shows three variables (`shape`, `color`, `linetype`) for each legend entry, but I only want to show one.

Only one of the `aes()` values changes in this plot (`linetype`) but the other values correspond to specific variables, and should be kept uniform across the many plots on my website.  Simply removing the other `aes()` values from the plot is not a viable solution in my case, as I want them to change in other plots similar to this.  Also, hiding the legend and modifying the `tooltip` to show the information works but is not the desired end result.

When running, the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

#aes lists
solute_colors <- c("NO3" = "#BF1616")
source_shapes <- c("rain"= 21)
location_linetypes <- c("1"= 2,"2"= 1,"3"= 3)

#create dataframe
data <- data.frame(
  date = c(1966, 1970, 1972, 1979, 1989, 1990, 1998, 2000),
  concentration = sample(1:8),
  solute = c("NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3"),
  location = c("3", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "2"),
  source = c("rain", "rain", "rain", "rain", "rain", "rain", "rain", "rain")
)

#ggplot
ggplot(data, aes(x= date, y= concentration, linetype= location, color= solute, shape= source))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = source_shapes) +
  scale_color_manual(values = solute_colors)+ 
  guides(shape = F, color = F)+ #removes shape and source legends in ggplot, but not in ggplotly
  scale_linetype_manual(values = location_linetypes)
```

the legend only shows the `linetype`, which is the desired outcome(seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDZvR.jpg)).  However, when wrapping it in `ggplotly`

```
#ggplot p
p<-ggplot(data, aes(x= date, y= concentration, linetype= location, color= solute, shape= source))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = source_shapes) +
  scale_color_manual(values = solute_colors)+ 
  guides(shape = F, color = F)+ #removes shape and source legends in ggplot, but not in ggplotly
  scale_linetype_manual(values = location_linetypes)
#wrap p in ggplotly
ggplotly(p)
```

the legend shows up with the three `aes()` values within the same line on the legend as seen

[image: here].

How do I override this change when wrapping in `ggplotly` or manually code in the legend for it?  I have added themes within ggplot that change the legend in both `ggplot` and `ggplotly` just fine (such as `legend.position` and `legend.title`) though I have not found anything to control the actual variables shown.

I am using R version 3.4.0 (RStudio version 1.0.143) on Windows 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know how to force `ggplotly` to respect your legend labels but you can manually overwrite virtually everything.

```
gp <- ggplotly(p)
gp[['x']][['data']][[1]][['name']] <- '1'
gp[['x']][['data']][[2]][['name']] <- '2'
gp[['x']][['data']][[3]][['name']] <- '3'
gp
```

[image]